# Desativar Auto Redirecionamento após login no CakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, auth

Estou usando o Auth do CakePHP 2.4 e se tento acessar um link que precisa de login ele redireciona para o form de login. Por exemplo:

Tento acessar: /projetos/edit/34 sem estar logado. Então o CakePHP redireciona para /login. Após informar o usuário e senha e autenticar o próprio CakePHP me redireciona para /projetos/edit/34. Ok, até ai tudo certo, mas acontece que quando acesso a página inicial do meu projeto e clico no link de login (indo para /login a partir da /) e autentico ele me redireciona para a página anterior, no caso a inicial do meu projeto.

Eu gostaria que neste caso fosse redirecionado para /painel

Como desativar esse auto redirecionamento no CakePHP somente para actions específicas?

Segue meu AppController.php

```php
class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array(
'DebugKit.Toolbar',
'Session', 
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User', 
                'fields' => array('username' => 'usuario', 'password' => 'senha'), 
                'scope' => array('User.status' => 1)
            )
        ), 
        'authorize' => 'Controller', 
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), 
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'painel'), 
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'), 
        'authError' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar.' 
    )
);

 public function isAuthorized($user){
    return true;
}

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

}
```

Dois casos:

Primeiro:

- Usuário tenta acessar diretamente o link /projetos/edit/34 sem logar.
- Auth do CakePHP não permite acesse e redireciona para /login
- Após usuário se logar Auth redireciona para /projetos/edit/34

No primeiro caso está ok, entendido e funcionando como deveria. Agora no segundo caso:

- Usuário entra na página inicial do site /
- Usuário clica no menu "Login" e vai para o form de login em /login
- Usuário loga e é redirecionado para a página inicial /

Neste segundo caso, eu não gostaria que ele fosse para a página inicial mas sim para o que estiver configurado em loginRedirect no caso para /painel

Comment: Pode postar o código de como você configurou o componente Auth?

Comment: AppController.php adicionado

Comment: Que bom que você resolveu! Você poderia editar a pergunta retirando a solução, e postando essa parte como uma resposta? Fica mais adequado à proposta do site. E você pode/deve aceitar a própria resposta neste caso. Obrigado!

Comment: Ah sim, fiquei na dúvida se era para editar ou adicionar nova resposta. Vou editar.

Answer (score 5):

Com as dicas fiz o seguinte e o que eu queria foi resolvido:

No `AppController.php` adicionei uma matriz com os links que quero desativar o auto redirect.

```php
public $cfg = array(
    'disabledAuthAutoRedirect' => array('/')
);
```

E no `UsersController.php` meu método `login` ficou assim:

```php
public function login(){

  if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()){
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
  }

  if ($this->request->is('post')){

    if ($this->Auth->login()){

      if ($this->Session->check('Auth.redirect')){

        if (in_array($this->Session->read('Auth.redirect'), $this->cfg['disabledAuthAutoRedirect'])){
          return $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
        }
      }

      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }

    $this->Session->setFlash('Usuário ou senha inválidos, tente novamente.');

    unset($this->request->data['User']['senha']);
  }
}
```

Agora é só adicionar mais itens na matriz `$cfg` \o/

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer isso:

Apenas resumindo o código abaixo, o que você deve fazer é apenas adicionar esta instrução após o login:

```php
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

Desta maneira o login funciona das maneiras que você espera:

- Se o usuário acessar uma página que necessita login, era será redirecionado para ela novamente após o login
- Se o usuário clicar em login (no frontend por exemplo), e efetuar o login, será redirecionado para o **loginRedirect**

**Testado na versão 2.4.3 Stable**

## Login

```php
/**
 * login method
 *
 * @param 
 * @return void
 */    
public function login(){

  $this->layout = 'login';

  if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if($this->Auth->login()) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login efetuado com sucesso!'), 'flash/admin/success');
      $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuário e/ou senha incorretos'), 'flash/admin/error');
      $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
  }

}
```

## Logout

```php
/**
 * logout method
 *
 * @param 
 * @return void
 */
public function logout() {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Logout efeutado com sucesso!'), 'flash/admin/success');
  $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

## AppController.php

```php
'Auth' => array(
  'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
      'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
    )
  ),
  'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
  'logoutAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin' => false),
  'loginRedirect' => '/admin',
  'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
  'authError' => 'Acesso não permitido.'
),
```

---

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza, mas acho que o Cake está se comportando da maneira esperada – do ponto de vista dele. Você pode tentar interceptar o acesso à action no próprio controller e forçar um redirecionamento.

**No Controller Users:**

```php
public function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->action === 'login' && $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'painel'));
    }
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria que para certas actions ele não considerasse o auto redirecionamento e não verificar se está logado ou não.

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível, somente fazendo a verificação antes pra poder fazer o redirecionamento que você quer...

Comment: Alterei com dois casos. Não estou achando uma forma de verificar a página prévia. Acredito que ele guarda em session a página anterior ao login.

Comment: @rodrigoum Só estou verificando se está logado para não redirecionar caso não esteja. E você teria de incluir isso em cada controller/action que deseje tratar como caso especial. O destino do redirect o cake guarda na sessão, se não me engano na chave `Auth.redirect`.